# Rails4: NoMethodError in UsersController#show, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'd like to develop an app for schedule.
Each user create their own schedule.

I'd like to display the data as followings;

```
schedule title (user name)

  day1(mm/dd,yyyy)
    09:00 Math
    11:00 Science
    Room name A

  day2(mm/dd,yyyy)
    10:00 Physics 
    13:00 Music
    Room name B
```

How can I display course information in the event model?

e.g. title (Math, Science), time (from, to)...

The following error appeared when I try to display the page.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `event' for #<Room:0x007fb2149a1ac8>
Did you mean?  events
           events=):
  app/views/schedules/_schedule.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_schedules__schedule_html_erb___2809280481749604534_70201410929300'
  app/views/schedules/_schedule.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_schedules__schedule_html_erb___2809280481749604534_70201410929300'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1629176981125983348_70201561746560'
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedlues
  has_many :rooms, through: :schedules
  ...
```

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms
  ...
```

room.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedlue
  has_many :events
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
```

(Although I think 'room has_many events' is improper, I don't have any idea.)

schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    ...
end

create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    ...
end

create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "room_name"
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    ...
end

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time     "from"
  t.time     "to"
  t.string   "title"
    ...
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @schedules = @user.schedules.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  ...
```

show.html.erb

```
    <% if @user.schedules.any? %>
      <ol class="schedules">
        <%= render @schedules %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @schedules %>
    <% end %>
```

_schedule.html.erb

```
<li>
  <p>
  <% schedule.room.each do |a| %>
    <p><b>Day <%= a.day %></b></p>
    <% a.event.each do |e| %>  #error occur
      <% if e.title.any? %>
        <%= e.title %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <p>room: <%= a.room_name %></p>
  <% end %>
  </p>
</li>
```

Comment: your error says `undefined method 'event' for #<Accomodation`. Which means you are trying to call 'event' on an Accomodation instance and the method doesn't exist. You didn't paste your Accomodation class, but if you write the `event` instance method this particular error will be addressed. This doesn't solve your question `How can I display course information in the event model?`, which is a little too broad for me to want to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @max pleaner. I made a typo, I use 'room' insted of 'accomodation'. It would be appreciated if you could give me hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, `Room` does not have a method `event`. The reason is that in your model, you have `has_many :events`, which gives you an `Association` and not a single event. So try:

```
room.events.first
```

or something like

```
room.events.each do |event|
  puts event
end
```

This should fix the error you're getting now.

**EDIT** I forgot to look at your template. The following line is wrong:

```
<% a.event.each do |e| %>
```

The solution is, as mentioned above:

```
<% a.events.each do |e| %>
```

It is by the way interesting that you didn't get an error on `schedule.room`. That is wrong as well, it must be `schedule.rooms`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jdno. It works after using '<% a.events.each do |e| %>'. I also removed '<% if e.title.any? %>' because of error.